# Filter an Array of strings using Filtered String and Remove from Original Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, array-splice

I want to remove some elements from the array containing the word Evil (**filterString**).

```
let guests = ["Partner", "Evil Nice Relative 1", "Nice Relative 2", "Evil One", "another evil", "another one", "another evil is here", "strange Evil is here", "someone Nicer", "Ugly Evil Bad"];

const filteredArray = [];
const filterString = "Evil";

function checkEvil() {
    guests.filter((element, index) => {
        if (element.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
            console.log(index);
            guests.splice(index,1);
        } else {
            filteredArray.push(element);
        }
    });
    console.log(guests);
}
```

Here is what I get for the original array (**guests**):

```
    ['Partner', 'Nice Relative 2', 'another evil', 'another one', 'strange Evil is here', 'someone Nicer']
```

Just want the **guests** array updated once the desired string (**Evil**) is filtered.

Comment: Look into `filter` and `includes` or `indexOf` methods, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Somehow the original code didn't show up here. Edited the question.

Comment: Look into how filter method works, it returns new array of elements and when the output of callback is true that element is returned, so you don't need to use additional arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to mutate the original array then you can do as:

```js
let guests = [
  "Partner",
  "Evil Nice Relative 1",
  "Nice Relative 2",
  "Evil One",
  "another evil",
  "another one",
  "another evil is here",
  "strange Evil is here",
  "someone Nicer",
  "Ugly Evil Bad",
];

const filterString = "Evil";

function checkEvil() {
  for (let i = guests.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const element = guests[i];
    if (element.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
      guests.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  console.log(guests);
}

checkEvil();
```

---

**1)** You can easily achieve the result using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) as:

```js
const arr = [
  "Partner",
  "Nice Relative 2",
  "another evil",
  "another one",
  "strange Evil is here",
  "someone Nicer",
];
const result = arr.filter((s) => !s.match(/evil/i));
console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can also do this using forEach and match as:

```js
let guests = [
  "Partner",
  "Evil Nice Relative 1",
  "Nice Relative 2",
  "Evil One",
  "another evil",
  "another one",
  "another evil is here",
  "strange Evil is here",
  "someone Nicer",
  "Ugly Evil Bad",
];

const filteredArray = [];
const filterString = "Evil";

function checkEvil() {
  guests.forEach(element => {
    if (!element.match(/evil/i)) filteredArray.push(element);
  });
}
checkEvil();
console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: Somehow the original code didn't show up here. Edited the question.

Comment: @Tahir Nothings change, so you can still use filter and match here

Comment: @Tahir Another answer added. Have a look

Comment: But I do want to update the original array **guests**.

Comment: If you want to update the original array then why are you using `filteredArray`

Comment: Just for test purposes. I will have some other operations on the **guests** array so I need that one to be updated.

Comment: @Tahir another solutin added. Hope this is what exactly you want...

Comment: Thanks @decpk. Exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

define a pattern and then filter by it

```js
var arr = ['Partner', 'Nice Relative 2', 'another evil', 'another one', 'strange Evil is here', 'someone Nicer'];
const PATTERN = 'EVIL';
arr = arr.filter(str => str.toUpperCase().indexOf(PATTERN) === -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var list = ['Partner', 'Nice Relative 2', 'another evil', 'another one', 'strange Evil is here', 'someone Nicer'];
    var new_list = [];

    for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        if(!list[i].toLowerCase().includes('evil')) {
            new_list.push(list[i]);
        }
    }

    console.log(new_list);
</script>
```

Comment: Let's say beginner technique )

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your array where the value of each doesn't contain *`'evil'`* word:

```js
const arr = ['Partner', 'Nice Relative 2', 'another evil', 'another one', 'strange Evil is here', 'someone Nicer'];
const filteredArr = arr.filter(val=>!val.toLowerCase().includes('evil'))
console.log(filteredArr)
```